# Ruby on Rails model naming. How to name Ruby on Rails Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop

i'm creating site for fuel consumption accounting. I'm to create model for fuel consumption, and i'm curious how to name rails model for that purpose?

i have fuel consumption, and users, whom should account their fuel consumptions on site.

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough information: how is fuel tracked, what units are used, who is putting in the information, etc.

Comment: What does each instance of the model correspond to in the real world? A journey? Travel in a particular time period? The use of a tank of fuel?

Answer (score 0):

The basic conventions we use are

1. **Model** - Singular

   Example: For users the model name will be - User
2. **Controllerr** - Plural

   Example: For users the controller name will be - UsersController
3. **Routes** - Plural

   Example: For users the routes will be - users

   ```
    resources :users
   ```

Refer [Rails Naming Conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions)